# How to convert a ppk to an openSSH private key encrypted with a passphrase

Tags: putty, openssh, private-key, ppk

When I exported my private key in PuttyGen, I assumed that the passphrase I set was also used on the openSSH version. I'm finding that the passphrase I put in isn't working. What's the right way to export my private key in openSSH format with a passphrase?

To transfer the exported ssh key to linux, I just pasted it into nano, and tried to ssh-add it. It prompts me for a passphrase, but doesn't accept the one I gave it. PuttyGen imports it fine with that passphrase tho..

Comment: Try to rephrase your question, using terms "password" and "passphrase" correctly. You seem mistake one for another, making your question hard to follow.

Answer (score 1):

The Windows PuTTYgen's "Export OpenSSH key" *does* encrypt the key with 3DES-CBC. If the passphrase is non-empty, the output file says so:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
Proc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED
DEK-Info: DES-EDE3-CBC,157A04D5AE43F45B

NiGUXnTOhATzg4dGvyXs8rzetF7KpplJJIKrZvQunXuVcZhVS+NTpnTgwJb+zOCm
...
```

I've tested this on various versions over the past 4 years. If the passphrase is empty, I even get an "Are you sure?" prompt.

The Linux `puttygen` also always uses the same passphrase when converting.

---

For RSA & DSA keys, OpenSSH uses the same 'raw' key format as OpenSSL. So if 3DES-CBC is not sufficient, you can use the [`openssl`](http://www.slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html) command-line tool to reencrypt them:

```
openssl rsa -aes-128-cbc < old.key > new.key
```

On Unix of course OpenSSH's own `ssh-keygen` is better:

```
ssh-keygen -p -f old.key
```

Comment: So the strange thing is that if I export the key, copy it to a centos machine, and do an ssh-add, it asks for the passphrase and when i put it in, it tells me its incorrect. If i press enter when it prompts me, it quits without comment - which i was taking to be passwordless entry. I can see via ssh-add -l that no keys have been loaded. So why is my key's password not working?

Comment: Is whitespace important before or after the "begin/end RSA private key" parts? The way I created my key was just to paste it in nano.

Comment: @BT: Yes; you can have empty lines and stuff around the whole key, but not inside the key.

Comment: Hm, thats what I thought. Very strange..

Comment: @BT In particular all line breaks within the dash-BEGIN to dash-END block must remain the same, including exactly one blank line between DEK-Info and the first base64. Does `openssl rsa <key` give any different/better error message? Is your passphrase entirely ASCII printable characters? (Others may work differently depending on Windows regional settings and Linux locale.)